# Vim vim-airline on split view, change colors

Tags: plugin-airline

I tried [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) and it looks nice, while editing on single window.

When in split view, with multiple files open, I noticed it focus on current window. By focus I mean the other windows keep lights off (I mean I cannot see the infos on the bar, or at least is very difficult).

Comparing to what I had before. This is good because I can imidiatelly see where I am (in which window). Previously I had to look down on the left side to i.e. check the mode.

But, I'm missing one thing. I can't even see the filename on the other windows. So if I need to jump to file1.txt I have to look on the contents of the other windows to find it.

How do I change it so that at least the file name on the other split views (windows) becomes easier to see from distance?

[image]

I have other plugins also: Mark--Karkat  conoline.vim  nerdcommenter tabular

Comment: speaking as airline maintainer here, this is definitly not the default behaviour. So how did you configure vim-airline?

Comment: I just followed the pathogen installation instructions, nothing more.

Comment: any other plugins installed?

Comment: please show a screenshot of this as well

Comment: Question edited to mention other plugins and screenshot. Anything else I can provide?

Comment: Ahm, the filename is mentioned in the statusline. I don't understand the problem

Comment: To my eyes it looks too difficult to see. May I change the color to white?

Comment: you could try a different theme.